# Bash Prompt Changes Colors on ls

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

My prompt is:

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[33m\]':)'\[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]':('\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \e[0;1m\w\e[1m\n\$ "
```

The problem is when I use ls, the prompt changes colors to the color of the last line outputted with ls. For example, if I have a file named z, the prompt changes to grey (to match the color of files from ls) after typing ls, and this behavior is driving me nuts.

Anyone know how I can fix that? I want the entire prompt set to white, with the smilies colored differently.

(My prompt spits out a :) or a :( based on the outcome fo the last command, shows the directory path of pwd, then drops to a new line for command input)

I've enabled force_color_prompt to no avail.

Comment: Are you open to resetting your prompt entirely, or is that not an option?

Comment: That depends I suppose. Is there something in the functionality of my prompt that's causing the issue? I didn't have this problem before on my universities open suse server since ls had no colorize option there, so I assume it's ls colorize that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

New prompt (with \u@\h added, since I forgot that) is

```
export PS1="\e[0;1m\u@\h]\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[33m\]':)'\[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]':('\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \e[0;1m\w\e[1m\n\$ "
```

adding the `e[0;1m\` at the very beginning of the prompt began the colorizing of the prompt. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Essentially the prompt changed colors because the terminal changed from the previous color ouputted by ls. I thought that was the problem before but couldn't figure out the syntax needed to colorize the first bit.